# Add row to DataTable with custom attributes <td> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to add a row to DataTable dynamically while specifying not only the data the table cell will hold but also the attributes `<td>` tag will have.

> right now i have this code

```
let row = [
        '1',
        model.name,
        model.surname,
        model.personal_id,
        model.phone_number,
        model.loan_total_amount+'&nbsp;'+model.currency_code,
        model.loan_current_liability+'&nbsp;'+model.currency_code,
        model.pay_date,
        model.transaction_id || '',
        statuses[model.status],
        `<ul class="icons-list">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="datatable_basic.htm#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-menu7"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                    <li><a href="datatable_basic.htm#"><i class="icon-paperplane"></i> send sms</a></li>
                    <li><a href="datatable_basic.htm#"><i class="icon-diff-removed"></i>mark as payd</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>`
    ];

    let node = paymentsTable.row.add(row).draw();
```

I want to be able to do something like this

```
paymentsTable.row.add([
   { html : 'some html', className: 'some class', data-whatever:'whatever' },
   { html : 'some another html', className: 'some class', data-whatever:'whatever' }
])
```

In this case first cell in added row will have content of 'some html' class of 'some class' and data-whatever of 'whatever'

Comment: You cannot. the docs clearly states that.  Use the `createdCell` callback or use some simple chaining on the inserted nodes.

Answer (score 2):

When you add a Row in datatable, you can get this new created `row object` as follow:

```
var rowNode = oTable
      .row.add([cellData, cellData, cellData, cellData, cellData, cellData])
      .draw(false)
      .node();
```

You can inject your `CSS class` in desired `td` of this new created row.

```
$(rowNode).find('td:eq(1)').addClass( 'myClass' );
$(rowNode).find('td:eq(3)').addClass( 'myClass2' );
```

See this [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/ojyojfte/) for demonstration.

Comment: You could even do it all in one line, here an example of using chaining to the extreme -> `table.row.add(['test', 'test2']).nodes().to$().find('td:eq(0)').addClass('someClass').attr('data-whethever', 'whatever').end().find('td:eq(1)').addClass('someOtherClass')` etc etc **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/929/** but I think I would create a small `add()` plugin that did the trivial job instead.